# Resource request: Function spaces properties

Tags: fa.functional-analysis

Is there any resource (book, article,...) that presents all the basic function spaces (Metrizable, Normed, Banach, Sobolev, Hilbert, $L^p$, C[a,b], etc.) together with their properties (completeness, separability, reflexivity, compactness, and other special properties maybe...,etc) and diagrams with arrows (which space is also other space> example Normed Space is also a Metrizable space)?

I find it difficult to search anytime properties of these spaces...

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Terry Tao wrote [a blog post describing the following "type diagram of function spaces"](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/11/a-type-diagram-for-function-spaces/) a few years ago:

[image: Tao's type diagram for function spaces]

The axes are labeled by exponents $s$, corresponding to the *regularity* and $p$ corresponding to the *integrability*. See the blog post for more details.

Answer (score 8):

Some good references are

> Dunford, Nelson, and Jacob T. Schwartz. Linear Operators Part I: General Theory. Vol. 7. New York: Interscience publishers, 1958.

(Chapter IV. Special Spaces)

> Johnson, William B., and Joram Lindenstrauss. Handbook of the geometry of Banach spaces. Vol. 1. Elsevier, 2001.

(The first contribution "Basic concepts in the geometry of Banach spaces" is quite instructive.)

> Triebel, Hans. Theory of function spaces (I-III), Springer

(As the title says, its more focused on function spaces…)